# Tumblr custom domain/CNAME

Tags: dns, tumblr, cname

I have a blog on Tumblr (faithfullforever.tumblr.com) which uses the custom domain www.mariannefaithfull.fm. Yesterday I shortly deactivated the custom domain on Tumblr to export content.

When I tried reactivating the custom domain on Tumblr it did not work anymore and it looks like they changed the way you have to set up things on your domain provider, so I had to fiddle with things over there. I managed to change the IP so that it points to Tumblr.

When you open www.mariannefaithfull.fm you get to Tumblr, but not my blog. The Tumblr settings page is giving me the following message when I test the domain.

[image]

I just want to make sure that this isn't a problem with the way I have set up things on my provider, but simply the waiting period of up to 72 hours. [Tumblr's FAQ](https://tumblr.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/231256548-Custom-domains) is not a very great help to me nor did my research on Google bring me any further on understanding how to set up a CNAME.

This is what the panel for changing records looks like on my provider. What exactly do I have to change/fill in to so that Tumblr can read the CNAME?

Name, TTL, Type, Priority, Value

[image: See Image]

Comment: Take a look at Namecheap's guide to Tumblr with public domains, it may be helpful: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9247/2208/how-do-i-use-my-domain-with-my-tumblr-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem just a couple of days ago. Though it's back to normal now so I suggest waiting until tomorrow; it should resolve itself :)

Comment: Thanks, hopefully that will be the case with me. I just should have not fiddled with it in the first place!

Comment: Oh, but can you tell if I set up the CNAME right just from the screenshot? It would be great help. Thanks.

Comment: Ah you're right, after your question edits, your image shows. I don't read German well but it looks like your 'Name' field and 'Wert' field may need to be swapped. (The Name should be your domain, the Wert should be tumblr).

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't notice the images weren't showing right until I fixed a spelling error. :) Wert means value and Name, well, name! Thanks!

Comment: After some more fiddling around I figured out what my mistake was. I had to add an additional A-Record pointing to Tumblr's IP even though in their instructions it says EITHER add an A-Record OR a CNAME. Also on Tumblr's side I had to omit the www. in front of the URL when testing.

Answer (score 2):

Check on http://www.whatsmydns.net/. Is IP still pointing to tumblr or your own.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the screenshot you provided of your DNS interface, I think you want the following:

```
Name   TTL     Type    Priorität   Wert
www    10800   CNAME               domains.tumblr.com.
```

Your subdomain is `www` and you want it to point to `domains.tumblr.com.`

The trailing dot here is important, otherwise `www` would become a CNAME for `domains.tumblr.com.mariannefaithfull.fm`, which would not be helpful  :o)